# Align button to bottom, but keep in flow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-position, vertical-alignment

Is it possible to align a button to the bottom of it's parent element, but keep it in the flow so that space is made for it?

I know how to align a button to the bottom use `position: absolute; bottom:0` but that makes text overwrite it ([example](http://plnkr.co/edit/oPPbfp?p=preview)).

I would prefer not to have to hard code the height of the button as bottom padding for the parent element.

Comment: Comments on the downvotes would be helpful, this is probably a silly question for one reason, but I am not sure why exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding bottom for parent equal to button height, then text won't go over button.

```
here is fiddle example 
http://jsfiddle.net/t0e9hhn9/
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without hard coding in the height of the button?

Comment: you can allways create js or jquery helper function to get button height and set padding-bottom to parent